# How to download the following scraping data in CSV file in following printing format?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know how to download data in csv file .I just want to know how i can append the print data in an array with the same printing format then i can download it in CSV file

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.physiotherapyexercises.com/Js/Data/ExerciseData_English_2019_12_06_00_49_56.js'

data = json.loads(re.search(r'exerciseRecords=(.*?]);',
                        requests.get(url).text).group(1))

 # uncomment this to print all data:
 # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for exercise in data:
  print(*exercise['Texts'], sep='\n')
  print('-' * 80)
```

Comment: So you've scraped the website, and have downloaded data in `data` and you now want to save that to CSV? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service - you should try to write your own code and come here when you have a problem with it. So, what have you tried? There are examples of writing to CSV in the Python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion .I know how to download data in csv file .I just  want to know how i can append the print data in an array with the same printing format then i can download it in CSV file

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, because description not clear:

```
import re
import csv
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.physiotherapyexercises.com/Js/Data/ExerciseData_English_2019_12_06_00_49_56.js'

data = json.loads(re.search(r'exerciseRecords=(.*?]);',
                        requests.get(url).text).group(1))


with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['text', ]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for exercise in data:
      print(*exercise['Texts'], sep='\n')
      print('-' * 80)
      writer.writerow({'text': '\n'.join(exercise['Texts'])})
```